# Initializing A Variable With Its Default Constructor

Tags: c++, initialization

**Question:**

Is there a difference between the following initializations?

(A) What exactly is the second one doing?

(B) Is one more efficient than the other?

```
int variable = 0;
int variable = int();
```

This question also applies to other data types such as std::string:

```
std::string variable = "";
std::string variable = std::string();
```

**Background:**

I basically got the idea [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20731/in-c-how-do-you-clear-a-stringstream-variable) (the second code sample for the accepted answer) when I was trying to empty out a stringstream.
I also had to start using it when I began learning classes and realized that member variable initializations had to be done in the constructor, not just following its definition in the header. For example, initializing a vector:

```
// Header.h
class myClass
{
 private:
      std::vector<std::string> myVector;
};

// Source.cpp
myClass::myClass()
{
    for (int i=0;i<5;i++)
    {
         myVector.push_back(std::string());
    }
}
```

Any clarity on this will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Your two examples are very different because `0` is an `int` but `""` is not a `std::string`, it's a `const char [1]`.

Comment: Hmm, well I am still measuring these based on the output that they produce, thank you for insight though.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why use = to initialise a primitive type in C++?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/353632/why-use-to-initialise-a-primitive-type-in-c)

Comment: Just do `myClass::myClass()::myVector(5){}`. This is a X-Y problem. `int i(0);` `int i=0;`; `int i = int();` `int i = int(0)` are equivalent.

Comment: The `int` examples are equivalent, the `std::string` ones could be, depending on how the compiler optimizes the implementation of the ctors receiving no resp. a string literal member.

Comment: @user3528438 ...and their curly cousins from C++11 as well ;)

Comment: @user3528438 not exactly; `int i = int(0)` involves a temporary object but `int i = 0;` doesn't.  However, `string s = "";` is exactly the same as `string s = string("");`

Answer (score 0):

**Edit**

After reading again, I realized that you explicitely asked about the default constructor while I provided a lot of examples with a 1 parameter constructor.

For Visual Studio C++ compiler, the following code only executes the *default* constructor, but if the copy constructor is defined explicit, it still complains because the never called copy constructor can't be called this way.

```
#include <iostream>
class MyInt {
public:
    MyInt() : _i(0) {
        std::cout << "default" << std::endl;
    }
    MyInt(const MyInt& other) : _i(other._i) {
        std::cout << "copy" << std::endl;
    }
    int _i;
};
int main() {
    MyInt i = MyInt();

    return i._i;
}
```

**Original** (typo fixed)

For int variables, there is no difference between the forms.

Custom classes with a 1 argument constructor also accept assignment initialization, unless the constructor is marked as `explicit`, then the constructor call `Type varname(argument)` is required and assignment produces a compiler error.

See below examples for the different variants

```
class MyInt1 {
public:
    MyInt1(int i) : _i(i) { }
    int _i;
};
class MyInt2 {
public:
    explicit MyInt2(int i) : _i(i) { }
    int _i;
};
class MyInt3 {
public:
    explicit MyInt3(int i) : _i(i) { }
    explicit MyInt3(const MyInt3& other) : _i(other._i) { }
    int _i;
};
int main() {
    MyInt1 i1_1(0); // int constructor called
    MyInt1 i1_2 = 0; // int constructor called

    MyInt2 i2_1(0); // int constructor called
    MyInt2 i2_2 = 0; // int constructor explicit - ERROR!
    MyInt2 i2_3 = MyInt2(0); // int constructor called

    MyInt3 i3_1(0); // int constructor called
    MyInt3 i3_2 = 0; // int constructor explicit - ERROR!
    MyInt3 i3_3 = MyInt3(0); // int constructor called, copy constructor explicit - ERROR!
}
```

Answer (score -3):

The main difference between something like:
`int i = int();` and `int i = 0;`
is that using a default constructor such as `int()` or `string()`, etc., unless overloaded/overridden, will set the variable equal to `NULL`, while just about all other forms of instantiation and declarations of variables will require some form of value assignment and therefore will not be `NULL` but a specific value.

As far as my knowledge on efficiency, neither one is "better".

Comment: What has `NULL` to do with anything here? Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7200674/is-null-defined-as-nullptr-in-c11, setting an `int` to `NULL` can be an error.

Comment: "int variable = int()" outputs 0.

Comment: `int i = int();
  bool b = (i == NULL);

  cout << b << endl;` prints out 1, true.

Comment: @m_callens: Did you look at the post I linked? The most you can say is "seems to work *for you*", because it's semantically broken, the standard does not guarantee it compiles, and there are better implementations where it does not.

Comment: @m_callens `NULL` is a macro defined to `0`

Comment: @MattMcNabb No it is a macro that is defined to be `(void*)0`. You can assign it to int in C, but C++ will give warning.

Comment: @texasbruce sorry but you are just wrong; the C++ standard defines that `NULL` is a macro for an integer literal with value zero. See C++14 [support.types]/3 and [conv.ptr]/1 for the exact text.

Comment: @MattMcNabb Well try it yourself.

Comment: @texasbruce the C++ standard is more authoritative than a compiler. If your C++ compiler gives an error for `int x = NULL;` then the compiler is broken (and, after checking you were invoking it in standard mode, you could report a bug).